# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} {\sin(1/x^2)} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$
 \lim_{x \to 0^+} \sin(1/x^2) = \sin(1/0) = \sin(\infty) = \infty
$$

Would this just go to infinity? Or I am missing something?

Comment: The limit does not exist. As $x\to 0^+$, the function $\sin(1/x^2)$ bounces more and more wildly over the interval $[-1,1]$

Comment: $\sin(\infty) = \infty$ is false.

Comment: This is an example of an essential singularity. It is neither removable, nor is it a pole. Therefore the limit as you approach 0 does not exist.

Comment: It can't go to infinity, because all values of $\sin$ are in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Here are [some pics of $\sin(1/x)$](http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/sin1overx/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $t=\frac{1}{x^2}$, you get $\lim_{t \to \infty} \sin t $ which doesn't exist